# Topological data analysis - where to begin

Tags: python, r, visualization, topology

I've recently come across 'topological data analysis' (TDA) as a unique way of visualizing large datasets.  Here is a Stanford paper with example output towards the end https://research.math.osu.edu/tgda/mapperPBG.pdf.

I'd like to produce similar results but am having difficulty finding runnable code on the net where you install a package, load sample data, then execute a few lines (like http://scikit-learn.org/ examples).  My language preference is Python but could use R as well.

Has anybody been able to get traction with TDA and if so, any advice on how to get code up and running?

Comment: The link is dead :-(

Comment: If one of the answers were helpful it would be great if you could accept it - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 8):

There is a new r package out:

[TDA: Statistical Tools for Topological Data Analysis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TDA/index.html)
This package provides tools for the statistical analysis of persistent homology and for density clustering.

The very well written vignette can be found here: [Introduction to the R package TDA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TDA/vignettes/article.pdf)

Abstract

> We present a short tutorial and introduction to using the R package
>   TDA, which provides some tools for Topological Data Analysis. In
>   particular, it includes implementations of functions that, given some
>   data, provide topological information about the underlying space, such
>   as the distance function, the distance to a measure, the kNN density
>   estimator, the kernel density estimator, and the kernel distance. The
>   salient topological features of the sublevel sets (or superlevel sets)
>   of these functions can be quantified with persistent homology. We
>   provide an R interface for the efficient algorithms of the C++
>   libraries GUDHI, Dionysus and PHAT, including a function for the
>   persistent homology of the Rips filtration, and one for the persistent
>   homology of sublevel sets (or superlevel sets) of arbitrary functions
>   evaluated over a grid of points. The significance of the features in
>   the resulting persistence diagrams can be analyzed with functions that
>   implement the methods discussed in Fasy, Lecci, Rinaldo, Wasserman,
>   Balakrishnan, and Singh (2014), Chazal, Fasy, Lecci, Rinaldo, and
>   Wasserman (2014c) and Chazal, Fasy, Lecci, Michel, Rinaldo, and
>   Wasserman (2014a). The R package TDA also includes the implementation
>   of an algorithm for density clustering, which allows us to identify
>   the spatial organization of the probability mass associated to a
>   density function and visualize it by means of a dendrogram, the
>   cluster tree.

Comment: I've had good results with this, even though I hadn't used R before.

Answer (score 2):

For visualization, [Cytoscape](http://cytoscape.org/) has desktop and browser versions.

It suggests two python libraries (Bioconductor and igraph) [here](http://cytoscape.org/what_is_cytoscape.html) to produce.

Answer (score 1):

Dionysus is a C++ implemenation computing persistent homology. It has a nice PyBind wrapper which makes it pretty easy to experiment with it in python.

Recently Dionysus version 2 has appeared which has plotting capabilities, which should make it easier to dive into. Have a look here:

http://www.mrzv.org/software/dionysus2/tutorial/plotting.html

From a generic dataset sitting in an euclidean space (i.e. for instance 2D or 3D arrays), building a Rips complex is probably a good entry point, this is explained here:

http://www.mrzv.org/software/dionysus2/tutorial/rips.html